RealityView Attachments on iOS 18 & Visually Appealing AR Labeling Alternatives
I want use SwiftUI views as RealityKit entities to display AR Labels within a RealityKit scene, and the labels could be more complicated than just text and window as they might include images, dynamic texts, animations, WebViews, etc. Vision OS enables this through RealityView attachments, and there is a RealityView support on iOS 18.
As I understand, RealityView attachments are not supported on iOS 18. I wonder if there is any way of showing SwiftUI views as entities on iOS 18 at this point. Or am I forced to use the text meshes and 3d planes to build the UI? I checked out the RealityUI plugin, but it's too simple for my use case of building complex AR labels. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!
Tried running RealityView attachments code samples from VisionOS on iOS 18. However, the code below gives errors on iOS 18:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct PassportRealityView: View {
    let qrCodeCenter: SIMD3<Float>
    let assetID: String

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content, attachments in
            // Setup your AR content, such as markers or 3D models
            if let qrAnchor = try? await Entity(named: "QRAnchor") {
                qrAnchor.position = qrCodeCenter
                content.add(qrAnchor)
            }
        } attachments: {
            Attachment(id: "passportTextAttachment") {
                Text(assetID)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                    .padding(5)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
    }
}

When I remove "attachments" keyword and the block, the errors are kind of gone. That does not help me as I want to attach SwiftUI views to Anchor Entities in RealityKit.
